# How to attach SSD to Azure VM and check its type?

Tags: windows, azure, ssd

I created one VM with 100G SSD, but it's only D rive, which is the temporary disk. I want to attach another SSD drive to the VM, but I'm not sure its type. Is is possible to do this?
Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Azure D-series VMs have an SSD as the resource disk. Once [Premium Storage](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/12/11/introducing-premium-storage-high-performance-storage-for-azure-virtual-machine-workloads/) is available you will be able to attach additional SSD disks to a VM of the DS-series (a new instance type that is essentially the D-series usable with Premium Storage). Premium storage is currently in limited preview.